# blanks inserted by do loops in macros

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm an absolute beginner in SAS, just started learning about macros, this example comes from the macro language reference of SAS 9.3 (p9) :

> ```
> %macro names(name= ,number= );
>   %do n=1 %to &number;
>     &name&n
>   %end;
> %mend names;
> ```
>
> [... ]
>
> ```
> data %names(name=dsn,number=5);
> ```
>
> Submitting this statement produces the following complete DATA
>   statement:
>
> ```
> data dsn1 dsn2 dsn3 dsn4 dsn5;
> ```

As I understand macros just insert text in the code, so I would expect it to produce the following statement: `data dsn1dsn2dsn3dsn4dsn5;`

What's happening and how could I produce the above statement with the same call ?

Comment: Just a note that SAS is on 9.4 so you may want to work off that version of the documentation, it has more examples at least. https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/SAS-9-4-Macro-Language-Reference-Has-a-New-Appendix/ta-p/291716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this, run the following code

```
%macro names_whitespace(name= ,number= );
  %do n=1 %to &number; &name&n %end;
%mend names;

%put %names_whitespace(name=dsn,number=5);

%macro names_nospace(name= ,number= );
  %do n=1 %to &number;&name&n%end;
%mend names;

%put %names_nospace(name=dsn,number=5);
```

Actually, in your macro `%names`, you inclide a *new line* and some *tabs* or *blanks* for each name you insert. These are called white space characters When executing a macro, SAS replaces succeding white space characters with one blank.